# many functions in a controller on AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-controller

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp" >
        <head>
            <title>myApp.html</title>
        </head>

    <body ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">

    <br><br>
    <div>

       <p> Inserisci un colore <input style="background-color:{{colore}}" ng-model="colore" value="{{colore}}"> </p>
        <body bgcolor="{{colore}}">
    </div>

    <div > 

       <p>Nome: <input style="background-color:{{colore}}" type="text" id="nome" onkeyup="" ng-model="vm.utente.nome"></p> 
       <p>Cognome: <input style="background-color:{{colore}}" type="text" id="cognome" ng-model="vm.utente.cognome"></p>

       <p id="prova" value="test">{{myFunction}}</p>
       <p>{{vm.saluta() | uppercase}}</p>

    </div>



       <p id="demo">prova</p>

        <button onclick= vm.myFunction()> Prova</button>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\myCtrl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

myCtrl.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function() {
        var vm=this;
        vm.utente = {nome: "Mario", cognome: "Rossi"}; 

        vm.saluta = function() {
            return "Buongiorno " +
                this.utente.nome + " " +
                this.utente.cognome + "!"

        };

        vm.myFunction = function() {
        var text = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text.toUpperCase();
        };

        function test2() {
         console.log("Hello!");
        };
    });
})();
```

i'm new on AngularJS and i can't understand my error. I see a lot of example in a single file (html with tag script) but i prefer to separate the controller with the html file.
in my mind, I intended to connect the controller without scope, simply replacing "this" with vm (var vm = this). I just want to do some simple tests with the functions, but i always get this error:

> myApp.html: 30 Uncaught ReferenceError: vm is not defined at
>   HTMLButtonElement.onclick (myApp.html: 30)

the first function work normally, i get the response from the "vm.saluto()" only if i call with the format: {{vm.saluto}}. why onclick and other not work?

Any help?
where is my mistake?

I am aware of the many cases similar to this, I have already displayed, but I have not found the solution

Comment: firstly you need quotes: `onclick= vm.myFunction()` -> `onclick="vm.myFunction()"`. Secondly use angularjs syntax `ng-click="vm.myFunction()"`

Comment: Try read the basics about using AngularJS. This will help you a lot.

Comment: Please correct your syntax and repost, thanks...

Comment: Yes, Both are correct even first read basics then repost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example, overall, should work.

Be aware that you have two body tags.

More importantly you should understand that the `vm` name you defined in `controller as` is not the same as the `vm` variable, which is local to your controller's function.

Finally you should avoid direct DOM manipulations when using AngularJS.

See example below:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.utente = {
      nome: "Mario",
      cognome: "Rossi"
    };

    vm.saluta = function() {
      return "Buongiorno " +
        this.utente.nome + " " +
        this.utente.cognome + "!"

    };
    vm.test = 'prova';
    vm.myFunction = function() {
      vm.test = vm.test.toUpperCase();
    };

    function test2() {
      console.log("Hello!");
    };
  });
})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<body ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <p>{{vm.utente.nome}}</p>
  <p>{{vm.saluta()}}</p>
  <button type="button" ng-click="vm.myFunction()">test</button>
  <p id="demo">{{ vm.test }}</p>
</body>

</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```